# How to sum two field in laravel mongodb?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.3

I get reference from here : https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

If in mysql query like this :

```
SELECT SUM(tota_salary), SUM(total_player) 
FROM club
WHERE code_club = 9
```

I want change it in laravel eloquent

From documentation laravel mongodb, I try like this :

```
Club::where('code_club', '=', 9)
     ->sum('total_salary')
     ->sum('total_player');
```

There exist error like this :

> Call to a member function sum() on float

If I only 1 sum like this :

```
Club::where('code_club', '=', 9)
     ->sum('total_salary');
```

It works

Why it failed when using 2 sum?

Comment: ofc, since the the sum method wont return the object but will return the sum value i guess

Answer (score 1):

here is a work around

```
  $clubs = Club::where('code_club', '=', 9)->get(); // or first() idk

 $data['sum_player'] = $clubs->sum('total_player');
 $data['sum_salery'] = $clubs->sum('total_salary');
```

Comment: It works. But when using `get` or `first`, it keeps longer. When I have some data on tens of thousands, it takes a lot of time to display data